# Opening files in a folder with Openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, tkinter, operating-system, openpyxl

I am currently trying to open the files in a folder with the below:

```
from tkinter import filedialog
import tkinter as tk
import openpyxl
import os

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()

folder = filedialog.askdirectory()

for f in os.listdir(folder):
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(f)
    ws = wb.active
    v = ws['A1']
    print(v.value)
```

After running this, I run into errors. The value for 'f' is 'filename.xlsx' but does not include the full file path so the file cannot be opened. Is there a way to add the rest of the path so that openpyxl can recognize the files? Is there anything else I should change?

Comment: The directory is `folder` and the file name is `f`. Just add them together.

Answer (score 1):

Just found the answer using [this guide](https://www.kite.com/python/examples/4286/os-get-the-path-of-all-files-in-a-directory)

```
from tkinter import filedialog
import tkinter as tk
import openpyxl
import os

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()

folder = filedialog.askdirectory()

for f in os.listdir(folder):
    path = os.path.join(folder,f)
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)
    ws = wb.active
    v = ws['A1']
    print(v.value)
```

Comment: Should be `os.path.join(folder, f)` instead of `os.path.join(dir, f)`.  I don't know why `dir` is created in this case.

Comment: You're right, I must have kept dir on accident when I was first creating this. Just edited my answer. Thanks!